# Declaring Variables, LIKE and booleans

Tags: sql, variables, boolean, sql-like

Can "LIKE" and a boolean behave the same way in a variable (IN SQL)? Or is there a way to do this?

I'm trying to declare a variable and have that variable be brought into my WHERE and everywhere else in my query.

```
DECLARE @SKU VARCHAR(10)
SET @SKU = LIKE 'RUSH%'

SELECT Name, SKU, Rate
FROM PriceTable
WHERE SKU = @SKU
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do what you're trying to do.  The variable is only a `VARCHAR`. It can't include logic.

This accomplishes the same thing, but the logic needs to be in the statements, not in the variable.

```
DECLARE @SKU_FILTER VARCHAR(10)
SET @SKU_FILTER = 'RUSH%'

SELECT Name, SKU, Rate
FROM PriceTable
WHERE SKU LIKE @SKU_FILTER
```

Comment: I'm always trying to cut corners! Thank you. Quick question though, say I want the variable to be disregarded throughout the query without having to manually do this. Is there something I can set it equal to that'll make this easy?

Comment: @supeercod `SET @SKU_FILTER = '%'` to disable the filter and bring back all results.